# RVM must cd to directory to change gemset according to .ruby-version & .ruby-gemset

Tags: ruby, bash, ubuntu, rvm

I found a strange behaviour with `RVM`, and don't know how to deal with it.

It seems RVM can't automatically change its gemset per `.ruby-version` & `.ruby-gemset` if I open a terminal exactly in the root of project. Please review what I mean

```
# open a terminal directly in terminal_ui directory, which contains .ruby-version & .ruby-gemset

ls -a # ... .ruby-version .ruby-gemset
rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-2.2.1 (found in /home/epic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1)
=> (default)
   fasteria
   global
   terminal
   terminal_ui

# but if I cd to the top and then back again, my gemset will be 

cd ../
cd terminal_ui
rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-2.2.1 (found in /home/epic/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1)
   (default)
   fasteria
   global
   terminal
=> terminal_ui
```

Helpful information:

```
 cat .ruby-version # => 2.2.1
 cat .ruby-gemset # => terminal_ui
 rvm -v # => rvm 1.26.11
```

I've tried `rvm get stable`, but with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RVM uses several hooks to change ruby version and gemsets on user actions:

- after_use
- before_install
- after_install
- after_do (Triggered after any 'do' action)
- after_cd (Triggered whenever a user uses the cd command)

When you open terminal just in project folder, you don't use command, so hook isn't called. But you can add following line in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file (after RVM-related lines):

```
cd .
```

It will cause RVM to use its hook and set proper gemset. More about hooks: [docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/hooks).

Comment: Simple as hell! Thanks!

Comment: BTW, on some ubuntus this functionality work well w/o any additions

Answer (score 0):

You can use .rvmrc for change automatically.

```
cd terminal_ui
touch .rvmrc
echo rvm use 2.1.1@terminal_ui >> .rvmrc
cd .
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `.rvmrc` is outdated version of what `.ruby-version` & `.rubgy-gemset` do